# Convergence in measure implies alternating sequences converges to zero in measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This problem came up in studying for a qual.

Suppose $\{f_{n}\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions that converges in measure to $f$. Prove that the sequence $\{g_{n}\}$, where $g_{n} = (−1)^{n}f_{n}$, converges in measure to a function $g$ if and only if $f= 0$ almost everywhere.

I have the converse direction. For the forward direction, I'd like to make use of the the fact that the $\{f_n\}$ admits a subsequence, say $\{f_{n_k}\} \to f$ point-wisely. Similarly, $\{g_{n_j}\} = \{(-1)^{n_j}f_{n_j} \} \to g$ point-wisely. Perhaps I can refine the subsequences and somehow use the fact that $(-1)^n$ diverges to arrive to the conclusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence $(g_{2n})$ converges in measure to $f$ and the sequence $(g_{2n+1})$ converges in measure to $-f$ hence $g=f$ and $g=-f$ almost everywhere, by uniqueness of the limit in measure. Hence, $f=0$ almost everywhere.